# VBA Macro that finds correct place to copy paste into

Tags: vba, excel

First of all hello guys,

I´m currently working on a VBA script as you may see from the title.
The thing is I only know some basic java and the things I looked up here and there to make my code running.

Now the thing is I want to have two sheets that synchronise.

To be more clear, if you write something in sheet1 and activate the macro it gets copied into the correct fields in sheet2.

My current code looks like this and i guess its the easiest way to get what I want to do:

```
    Sub magic()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Postenkosten")
    Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Monatskosten")

    Dim Pa As Integer
    Dim Pb As Integer
    Dim Ma As Integer
    Dim Mb As Integer

// go through the designated columns and rows
For Pa = 4 To 34 Step 3 
For Pb = 6 To 10 Step 1 

  // check if they are empty  
  If sh1.Cells(Pb, Pa).Value <> "" Then 

        //if not got to sheet2 and look the designated cells there
        For Ma = 1 To 30 Step 3
             For Mb = 1 To 12 Step 1
               //here comes the critical part - if my cell from sheet 1 is the same as the headline (cell) in sheet 2 then... 
               //if not look for the next headline and compare
               If sh1.Cells(Pb, Pa) = sh2.Cells(Ma, 2) Then
                 //make sure you have a empty row so you don't override things and copy the cells adjacent to sheet 2 
                 If sh2.Cells(Mb, Ma) = "" Then
                 Else
                       sh1.Cells(4, Pa).Value.Copy sh2.Cells(Mb, Ma)

                       sh1.Cells(Pb + 1, Pa).Value.Copy sh2.Cells(Mb + 1, Ma)
                       sh1.Cells(Pb + 2, Pa).Value.Copy sh2.Cells(Mb + 2, Ma)
                 End If
                End If
             Next Mb
        Next Ma

   End If
Next Pb
    Next Pa

    End Sub
       //go and do this for the next cell in sheet 1
```

I hope you get what I mean. If you have any ideas how to fix my code I would be very happy (I spent at least a week to make it work)

To further visualise the problem

[sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NYWa.png) 
[sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3yR1.png)

Thanks a lot for reading and trying to help.

If you need more information don't hesitate to ask I will provide as quick as possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after OP's request (see lines with `'<=== edited` comment)

maybe you need something like follows

```
Sub magic()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim postenDates As Range, monatDates As Range, cell As Range, fndRng As Range

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Postenkosten")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Monatskosten")

Set postenDates = SetDatesRange(sh1.Range("D6:D24"), 1, 10, 1, 3) '<== set base range and its "multiplying" factors as per your needs
Set monatDates = SetDatesRange(sh2.Range("A2:AJ2"), 3, 1, 18, 1) '<== set base range and its "multiplying" factors as per your needs

For Each cell In postenDates
    Set fndRng = FindDate(cell, monatDates)
    If Not fndRng Is Nothing Then
        If IsEmpty(fndRng.Offset(13)) Then               '<=== edited
            With fndRng.End(xlDown)                      '<=== edited
                sh1.Cells(4, cell.Column).Copy           '<=== edited
                .Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues    '<=== edited
                cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).Copy        '<=== edited
                .Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '<=== edited
            End With                                     '<=== edited
        End If
    End If
Next cell

End Sub


Function FindDate(rngToFind As Range, rngToScan As Range) As Range
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rngToScan
    If cell = rngToFind Then
        Set FindDate = cell
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell

End Function


Function SetDatesRange(iniRng As Range, nRowsSteps As Long, nColsSteps As Long, rowStep As Long, colStep As Long) As Range
Dim unionRng As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set unionRng = iniRng
With iniRng
    For i = 1 To nRowsSteps
        For j = 1 To nColsSteps
            Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, .Offset((i - 1) * rowStep, (j - 1) * colStep))
        Next j
    Next i
End With

Set SetDatesRange = unionRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
End Function
```

Comment: Over the course of the weekend I tried to fix a little flaw I found: The thing is the script copies the whole 3 cells to sh2, instead it should just copy the two cells ( - | x | x ) sitting right of the date and the header text. So the finished copy on our example looks like this ( HOWTO | ABC | 50€ ) --- If you could help me modifiying the already written code that would be awesome and the makro finally done cause everything else works as supposed :) - Greetings

Answer (score 1):

To keep the second `Worksheet("Sheet2")` synchronized with `Worksheet("Sheet1")`, you may place the VBA `Sub` shown below in the `Worksheet("Sheet1")` code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    r = Target.Row
    c = Target.Column
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target
End Sub
```

Thus, anything changed in the first Worksheet will be automatically reflected in the second one.

You can further modify this Sub pertinent to your particular requirements, for example setting the `Range` that should be reflected by using `Intersect` (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

Hope this may help.

Comment: Well a feature to constantly update the respective sheets is definitly an improvement. The main problem though is my code is not working as it should yet. It does nothing at all :/ I dont even get an error message ... it compiles but does not copy ABC | 50€ into sheet 2 under Jan 16 ... Thx for looking into it so quickly though

Comment: You can replace your non-working Sub macro magic() entirely with this working one, then modify it per you business logic if necessary. As per your description (i.e. " I want to have two sheets that syncronise. To be more clear, if you write something in sheet1 and activate the macro it gets copied into the correct fields in sheet2.") this solution is doing exactly what you described. Thanks and regards,

Comment: you are very helpful alex but as im a real beginner in vba i cant seem to make it work for my application ... did you look at the linked pictures? Also how does the private sub run (I´ve read you have to call it in another sub to make it work) - Is it necessery to add the intersect ? (also im not a native speaker so pls keep it as simple as possible :) )

Comment: I've already provided you with the working solution. To better understand how it works, refer to the online documentation (see the reference). You may further customize it for your purpose. You can accept the answer or not, but at this point I am closing this discussion because SO is not a free code writing service, neither online tutoring service. Best regards,